# Why is that output a "Bus error: 10" in a boost program (boost::filesystem)?

Tags: c++, macos, boost, g++, boost-filesystem

I successfully compile the program at the Question [How to pass a string type path to boost::filesystem:path's constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031898/how-to-pass-a-string-type-path-to-boostfilesystempaths-constructor) However, the output result shows more than the expected one.

```
Folder status: 0
Bus error: 10
```

The first line is the only expected result. I do not understand why the second one comes?

I get the following debug information by gdb:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/ZL/Desktop/mtfsg 
Reading symbols for shared libraries ++++............................. done
Folder status: 0

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00007fff5fc005a0
0x00007fff9046aab7 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char>>::~basic_string ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff9046aab7 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string ()
#1  0x00000001000018dd in main () at m.cpp:12
```

Comment: It's a bug. You'll need to debug to find out what the issue is. Run the program under your favorite debugger.

Comment: But any suggestion on how to debug under the g++ command line compiler? Or under the Mac OS X? I have little experience on debugging in C++.

Comment: Run the program under `gbd`. When it crashes, type `where`. Then you use `up` and `down` to navigate the stack frames and `print` to see the values of things.

Comment: I get the debug information by gdb. Please see the added information on the question area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the point of the error in my code:

In class OSxFS (tfs.h file), the method "string ShowStatus()" has an incorrect return type "string". This method does not need a return value since its functionality is only to print the directory (folder) status on the screen. So, I replace the "string" return type by "void".

The original code of method "string ShowStatus()"

```
**string** ShowStatus()
    {
      boost::filesystem::file_status folderStatus =
       boost::filesystem::status(mFolderPath);

      try
      {
        cout<<"Folder status: "<<boost::filesystem::is_directory(folderStatus)<<endl;
      }
      catch(boost::filesystem::filesystem_error &e)
      {
        cerr<<"Error captured: "<<e.what()<<endl;
      }
    }
```

The correct code:

```
**void** ShowStatus()
    {
      boost::filesystem::file_status folderStatus = 
       boost::filesystem::status(mFolderPath);

      try
      {
        cout<<"Folder status: "<<boost::filesystem::is_directory(folderStatus)<<endl;
      }
      catch(boost::filesystem::filesystem_error &e)
      {
        cerr<<"Error captured: "<<e.what()<<endl;
      }
    }
```